# How to point two domains to the same root directory in order to run multiple drupal sites

Tags: apache, drupal, dns, vhosts

I am trying to point two domains to the same root directory. They both shared the same nameserver and ip address. Now I created a file:

```
vhost.conf
```

I put this file in the http://firstdomain.com conf folder
The file has one line of code:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/seconddomain.com
```

The firstdoman.com is still not picking up the new root folder. And I do have two directories inside the /sites directory that are name after the two domains that both have a files and a settings.php file. And the default directory has not been modified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a YouTube Video that answers my question:

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?list=PL_aBy6EQRuXrysPXkkthzWVmkCBc0x2f9&feature=player_detailpage&v=LWxrC5vivAM
```